# Overlapping of controls

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm fairly new at coding so I need your help!!
I have controls overlapping. I have two richtextBoxes, one pictureBox and two buttons where richtextBoxes have the same location and size. The pictureBox overlaps on the left half of richtextBox. All but buttons are hidden when the form initializes. Here's how the code flows:
`

```
private void Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
richtextBox2.Visible = false;
richtextBox1.Visible = true;
pictureBox.Visible = true;
}
private void Button2_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
richtextBox1.Visible = false;
richtextBox2.Visible = true;
pictureBox1.Visible = true;
}
```

Button1_click works fine but when I hit Button2_click my richtextBox2 overlaps on the pictureBox1 whereas I want the pictureBox1 to always overlap all richtextBoxes.

Comment: Is it a typo that you have `pictureBox` in the first button, but `pictureBox1` in the second? Looks like you have two picture boxes and two rich text boxes...

Comment: Shoot my bad...yes it is a typo

Answer (score -1):

Go to the `[Design]` view of your form, right click `pictureBox1` and select "Bring to Front".

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks alot Arya! Much appreciated.